# Oracle UNION depending an IF conditon

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to make a SQL query wraping all of theses statements:

First, I have a first SQL query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NbOfEntries from table1 where colName = "some condition"
```

Then, I have another SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT 
  t2.col1 as col1, 
  t2.col2 as col2, 
  t3.col3 as col3 
FROM table2 t2 
  INNER JOIN table3 t3 
  ON t2.colName = t3.colName 
WHERE t2.colName = "some condition"
```

Finally, based on the first SQL statement, I have to add a row of fake data on the result of the second statement if `NbOfEntries > 0`. I have to add an `UNION` to the second SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
  "Dumb string 1" as col1,
  "Dumb string 2" as col2, 
  "Dumb string 3" as col3
FROM DUAL -- or something like that, I don't know how it works
```

I thought about using `UNION` but, I don't know how to use `UNION` with a condition. In addition, I do not know how to generate fake data with `SELECT` in Oracle, I have already looked at how `DUAL` works but I have not really been able to move forward.

Thank you.

**EDIT: Sample data**

If the first statement returns 0, I have these rows:

```
col1    col2  col3
A       AB    3
A       AC    7
A       AD    2
```

If the first statement returns > 0, I ihave to add one fake row to the result like this:

```
col1    col2  col3
A       AB    3
A       AC    7
A       AD    2
X       XX    0 // << Add this last row
```

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results to clarify your question.

Comment: @GMB I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT 
  t2.col1 as col1, 
  t2.col2 as col2, 
  t3.col3 as col3 
FROM table2 t2 
  INNER JOIN table3 t3 
  ON t2.colName = t3.colName 
WHERE t2.colName = "some condition"
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  "Dumb string 1" as col1,
  "Dumb string 2" as col2, 
  "Dumb string 3" as col3
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 from table1 
  where colName = "some condition"
)
```

There is no need to count the rows of `table1`.
`EXISTS` will return `TRUE` if there is 1 row that meets the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could jut use a `HAVING` clause for filtering:

```
SELECT t2.col1 as col1, t2.col2 as col2, t3.col3 as col3 
FROM table2 t2 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.colName = t3.colName 
WHERE t2.colName = 'some condition'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'X', 'XX', 0 
FROM table1 
WHERE colName = 'some condition'
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```